# Не работает шрифт

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Устанавливаю на страницу шрифт, взал с Google Fonts, вот так выглядит страница:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
 Какой-то текст
```

В итоге "Какой-то текст" выводится обыкновенным, стандартным шрифтом. В чем проблема?

Comment: В css прописали `font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;`?

Comment: Нет. Я думал можно либо через css, либо непосредственно в html. А нужно и там и там?

Comment: Я не знаю, что вы там в html пишете, но нужно прописать это свойство или же для всего документа (для `body`), или для какого-то конкретного элемента в стилях, т.е. css. А будет ли это в отдельном css-файле или инлайн - выбор за вами.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю проблема в том, что вы думали, что подключив css таблицу со стилями в html — у вас автоматически весь документ станет выводиться с подключенной шрифтовой гарнитурой. Но это не так работает.

Вы подключили шрифт, а дальше должны сказать браузеру, что нужно его использовать:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>body { forn-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; }</style>
  </head>
<body>
  Какой-то текст
</body>
</html>
```

Тогда внутри тега body будет использоваться подключенный вами шрифт.

Comment: Спасибо. А если несколько шрифтов на страницу нужно, добавлять несколько подключений придется?

Comment: Google fonts умеет формировать для нескольких гарнитур одну ссылку. Если вы добавляете шрифты непосредственно со своего сайта, то это можно сделать напрямую в css через [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face). В любом случае, вы подключаете гарнитуры, а затем указываете для каких элементов какую именно использовать.

Comment: Добавляю с Google Fonts. Каким образом сформировать одну ссылку для 2 шрифтов?